# Cyclotomic type criterion for unimodular matrices

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Here unimodular usually means $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ (but if you like you can also assume $A \in SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$.

In an article I read the following (the problem comes from representation theory of quiver algebras):

> A unimodular $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has all eigenvalues on the unit circle (this is called cyclotomic) if and only if we have $|Tr(A^k)| \leq n$ for all $k=0,...,n$. (maybe there is a typo in the article and it is meant $|Tr(A)^k| \leq n$ instead?)

Usually Im wrong when I find something that looks wrong in an article and since I got noone to ask this in the next weeks I thought about asking here (I can delete the thread in case I made a stupid thinking error,so please do not answer in case I just have a thinking error. ).

I think I found a counterexample with GAP (I post the GAP input/output so you can check it if you like):

Let $A$ be the following unimodular matrix (this is the coxeter matrix of the Nakayama algebra with Kupisch series [5,5,5,5,5,5,4,3,2,1]):

[ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], 
  [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1 ], [ 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], 
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1 ] ]

Then we have 
W:=[];for i in [0..10] do Append(W,[AbsoluteValue(Trace(g)^i)]);od;W;

[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]

and

W:=[];;for i in [0..10] do Append(W,[AbsoluteValue(Trace(g^i))]);od;W;

[ 10, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 6, 1, 2, 6 ] .

So by the above theorem, $A$ should be cyclotomic. But GAP gives me for the characteristic polynomial x_1^10+x_1^9-x_1^7-x_1^6-x_1^5-x_1^4-x_1^3+x_1+1 and wolfram alpha says it has a zero 1.17628... which does not lie on the unit circle: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x_1%5E10%2Bx_1%5E9-x_1%5E7-x_1%5E6-x_1%5E5-x_1%5E4-x_1%5E3%2Bx_1%2B1

> Question: In case there is really something wrong, can the criterion be fixed by using $|Tr(A^k)| \leq n$ for $i=0,1,...,f(n)$ instead (so we replace $n$ by a polynomial function $f(n)$. Maybe $f(n)=n^2$ already works (it does in this  example)).

It might be interesting to see what a "minimal" f(n) might look like (even if when it is not polynomial). For example how does $f(n)$ start for $n=2,3,...$ (in case it exists). Of course one might also think about this question for various types of matrices, such as $A \in SL(n,K)$ or $GL(n,K)$ , where $K$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

edit: Fun questions:

1) What is the number of cyclotomic 0-1 matrices with determinant 1? It seems to start with 1, 3, 27, 756, see https://oeis.org/A185149.

2) What is the number of cyclotomic 0-1 matrices with determinant 1 or -1? It seems to start with 1, 4, 48, 1536, see https://oeis.org/A011266.

Sadly my computer seems to be willing to calculate this only until n=4...

Comment: Please add a definition of *unimodular matrix*.

Comment: @DenisSerre In the article there seems to be no definition given, so Id think it is the usual definition of an integer matrix with determinant +1 or -1 (sometimes also just +1 is allowed), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix. Any coxeter matrix of an acyclic quiver algebra is an explicit example as it is the main source of examples in the article (and my example comes from this class of examples).

Comment: An $A\in SL(2,\mathbb R)$ has ev's on the unit circle if and only if $|\textrm{tr}\; A|\le 2$, so $f(2)=1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks, partial results are of course welcome. What might f(n) be for n=3?

Comment: Computer experiments showed that f(3)>=5 and suggest $f(3)=5$.

Comment: @Mare: I don't know about $n=3$. I just knew this ($n=2$) because it's a basic fact in the spectral theory of periodic operators (plus I guess it's trivial to check).

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't have much to do with matrices, I think. Since being cyclotomic and the trace are conjugacy invariants, we may as well assume that $A$ is in Jordan form, say $A=J+N$ with $J$ diagonal and $N$ upper nilpotent. Then WLOG, we may take $A=J$, since eigenvalues and traces of $J^k$ and $(J+N)^k$ are the same.

Now one direction is easy. If $A$ is cyclotomic with eigenvalues $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, then
$$ |\text{Trace}(A^k)| = |e_1^k+\cdots+e_n^k|\le |e_1|^k+\cdots+|e_n|^k=n. $$

For the other direction, let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, or for that matter, an arbitrary Galois invariant set of algebraic integers. If we assume that
$$  |e_1^k+\cdots+e_n^k|\le C\quad\text{for $k\ge1$,} $$
then by the usual formulas relating elementary symmetric polynomials to elementary power polynomials, the elementary symmetric polys of $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are bounded by a function of $C$ and $n$, so there are only finitely many possibilities for $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. But any set of powers $e_1^k,\ldots,e_n^k$ has the same property, so for each $i$, the sequence $(e_i^k)_{k\ge1}$ is a finite set, and hence every $e_i$ is a root of unity. (This is all more-or-less Kronecker's theorem, and can undoubtedly be proven more slickly.)

Comment: The issue here seems to be that the claim in the OP only needs to test the values of k between 1 and n (not infinitely many), which seems rather suspicious.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is more about a concrete $f(n)$ such that we have to look only at finitely many cases like for example $1 \leq k \leq n^2$. Can you give an explit $f(n)$ from your proof? And do you agree that $f(n)=n$ does not work in my example?

Comment: @Mare Thanks for the clarification. I missed that $k\le n$ condition. But I think my point is valid that this problem has very little to do with unimodular matrices. It's a problem about algebraic units generating an extension of degree $n$ whose first $n$ (or however many one wants to specify) power sums satisfy a specified bound. Given such units, one can build a unimodular matrix with the specified characteristic polynomial. I'm sure there are better estimates known, but if you just want some bound, there''s an old paper ...

Comment: @Mare ... of Blanksby that gives a bound: PROCEEDINGS OF  THE AMERICAN 
MATHEMATICAL SOCIETY Volume 49,  Number 1, May 1975. SUMS OF POWERS OF CONJUGATES OF  ALGEBRAIC NUMBERS, P.  E.  BLANKSBY, https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-049-01/S0002-9939-1975-0382180-5/S0002-9939-1975-0382180-5.pdf